# Export PDF, CSV, Excel form Datatable using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

I'm using this code and it is working fine.

But I want to get limited row data and limited words from a row from datatable.

What I'm doing Jquery code:

```
if( $('.clienttable').length > 0 ) {
        $('.clienttable').DataTable( {           
            pageLength: 10,
            responsive: true,
            dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [1, 2, 3,4,5,6]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [1, 2, 3,4,5,6]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [1, 2, 3,4,5,6]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [1, 2, 3,4,5,6]
                    },
                    title: 'List of Clients',
                }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                { targets: [0], orderable: false },
                { targets: [7], orderable: false }
             ],
            "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]]  
        });
    }
```

Frontend Code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover clienttable" >
</table>
```

Other Question:

**How to remove white spaces text in columns when excel export..?
 i m getting issues like white spaces in the excel table cell, can this be possible to remove white spaces..?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataTables Select extension: [DataTables Select](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/)

Add to button export options:

```
modifier: {
      selected: true
}
```

and

```
select: true
```

to initialize DataTable code.

Your new code:

```
if( $('.clienttable').length > 0 ) {
    $('.clienttable').DataTable( {           
        pageLength: 10,
        select: true,
        responsive: true,
        dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                    modifier: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                    modifier: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                    modifier: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                    modifier: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                },
                title: 'List of Clients',
            }
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: [0], orderable: false },
            { targets: [7], orderable: false }
         ],
        "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]]  
    });
}
```

Now you can print only selected rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... @Zafahix but is not working exactly what i want

Comment: @VishvakarmaDhiman 
So you need a function that prints, for example, the first 50 results?